# Prove that $\left\{\neg(\forall x \in M:a(x))\right\}\Leftrightarrow \left\{\exists x \in M: \neg a(x)\right\}$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

> Let $a(x)$, $x \in M$ be a form of statement.
>
> Prove that $\left\{\neg(\forall x \in M:a(x))\right\}\Leftrightarrow
> \left\{\exists x \in M: \neg a(x)\right\}$

I have started by trying to translate this to "human" language:

Exactly when not for all x in M a(x) is necessary, we have that there exists an x in M so that we have the negation of a(x).

Sorry my English but did I translate this correctly? My translation doesn't really help me finding a solution to this task though...

But the left side is saying that we have for all negations of x in M the negation a(x).

If every x, so says the left side, has a negation of a(x), then there basically must be (exists) at least one x which satisfies the right side. So it must be true for sure... Damn this is really complicated.

I would be very interested in seeing a correct proof of this, please.

Comment: For every $x$, the proposition $a(x)$ is true. Now let's take the negation of that statement; Is it clear for you, intuitively, that it goes like that, " There exist at least one  $x$ such that $a(x)$ is not true " ?

Comment: You don't need the curly braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to look at this is to know that the  negation of "all" is "not all", as opposed to "none at all."

Let $M$ be the set of all males. Let $a(x)$ denote "x is an A-student." So say we start with someone claiming $$\forall x \in M:a(x)$$

That means that what's being claimed is: "every male student is an A-student."

But perhaps Mary notices that the claim is false, because she knows for a fact that John (a male student) has only a C-average, and hence is not an A-student.

What Mary noted is a "counterexample" to the claim that **every** male student is an A-student. Hence, Mary is justified in concluding, "No....$$\lnot(\forall x \in M:a(x))\tag{1}$$  Indeed, she knows that *there exists a male student* (John) who is **not** an A-student, i.e., $$(\exists x \in M: \lnot a(x)).\tag{2}$$

That is, $(1),$ and $(2)$ are ***equivalent***

---

Note that the negation of $\exists x \in M: a(x)$ is $\lnot(\exists x \in M: a(x))$ which means that there does not exist any $x \in M$ such $a(x)$; which is equivalent to saying $(\forall x\in M: \lnot a(x))$

Comment: Would this really count as a proof?

Comment: It follows *definitionally*.  What is the negation of $\forall x, P(x)$?  That would be $\lnot (\forall x, P(x))$, which BY definition means "not all x satisfy P(x)", which, by definition means that "there exists at least one x, such that $P(x)$ is not true. I.e. $\exists x, \lnot (P(x))$.

Comment: The same thing can be defined starting with $\exists x, \lnot(P(x))$ which asserts the existence of at least one x in the set such that it is not true that $P(x)$ holds.  Which unequivocally means that not all x \in the set satisfy P(x), i.e. $\lnot \forall x, P(x).$

Comment: So we have each direction; starting from either side, we can almost  immediately infer the other side.  That is what is meant by $\iff$.

Comment: Would this be a valid proof of the task if I say: $\forall x \in M:a(x)$ is exactly true if and only if $a(x)$ is true for all $x \in M$ (definition from our readings). Now, here, it is saying that for all $x \in M$ we do not get $a(x)$. Thus this is equivalent if we say that there exists an $x$ such that we get  $\neg a(x)$ because of the fact none of the $x$ gives us $a(x)$.

Comment: Regarding the "real life" example in my post: You clearly seemed to need to understand that the negation of $\forall x a(x)$ is NOT "for NO $x, a(x)$. Rather, the negation of forall x ... is "not for all x". That is not equivalent to saying "there are no x...". Rather, when making a claim about all, to disprove it, we need only find the *existence* of one element that defies the claim. And hence, we know that *exists* at least one (perhaps there are other)  that defies the claim.

Comment: I think I understood it now, still I have huge troubles in writing the proof and seeing if it counts as a proof. I just tried it, one comment over your latest comment.

Comment: Every thing you write in your proof above is spot on, except for "because of the fact none of the x gives us a(x)".  Rather, "because of the fact that at least one of the x gives us $\lnot a(x)$.  But to be crystal clear in your proof:  I would start from "Now here" to say:  "Now, here, it is saying that "it is **not** the case that  for all $x\in M$, do we get $a(x)$. "Thus, this is equivalent to saying that there exists at least one x such that $\lnot a(x).$"

Answer (score 2):

> $$\left\{\neg(\forall x \in M:a(x))\right\}\Leftrightarrow
> \left\{\exists x \in M: \neg a(x)\right\}\tag{*}$$

Consider two statements in "human" language:

- (A) For every $x$ in $M$, $a(x)$ is true;
- (B) There exists $x$ in $M$ such that $a(x)$ is not true.

What $(*)$ says is that (A) is not true if and only if (B) is true.

To prove $(*)$, you need to show *two* directions:

- Suppose (B) is true, show  that  (A) cannot be true.
- Suppose (A) is *not* true, show  that  (B) must be true?